# Python - open lnk file with arguments (FlashProgrammer)

Tags: python, lnk

I need to open lnk file with arguments via Python. On the command line it looks like this:

```
FlashProgrammer -target=arm image.elf -device=xxxx -vdd=3V3 -erase=mass -program - secure
```

And it works. But how can I do this in Python? I tried something with subprocess, but got an error: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I think it is due of file extension.

Example code:

```
import subprocess

flash_programmer_path = "FlashProgrammer.lnk"

args = "FlashProgrammer -target=arm image.elf -device=xxxxx -vdd=3V3 -erase=mass -program - secure"

subprocess.run([flash_programmer_path, args])
```

Instead of *subprocess.run* I tried to use *subprocess.call* giving the same arguments as in the console. However, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @martineau added

Answer (score 0):

I should use *os.system(args)*. Then it works. Case closed.